# SVG clipPath issue on Firefox (88.0.1)

Tags: svg, firefox

I have an SVG image inside an SVG g element that has a clipPath applied to to it. Though the clipPath renders correctly and as expected on Chrome and Safari only part of the image seems to appear on Firefox (I'm on Firefox version 88.0.1 - OSX)

[Here is a link to a jsfiddle that recreates the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/LAD500/n5pzdcxm/1/)

On Chrome [it renders properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9V6n.png)

On Firefox [only part of the star renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lr91.png)

The other strange thing is that if I duplicate the path within the clipPath of the image seems to work in Firefox ([jsfiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/LAD500/n5pzdcxm/2/)) - which makes no sense to me.

```
<clipPath clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="clipPathMask-0f05a0aa-4fb7-420f-aea5-ad7fc9c9a127" transform="scale(0.005784982935153583 0.0038563296140941045)">
  <path d="M20.9,95.6l5.6-32.8L2.7,39.6l32.9-4.8L50.3,5L65,34.8l32.9,4.8L74.1,62.8l5.6,32.8L50.3,80.1L20.9,95.6z"></path>
  <path d="M20.9,95.6l5.6-32.8L2.7,39.6l32.9-4.8L50.3,5L65,34.8l32.9,4.8L74.1,62.8l5.6,32.8L50.3,80.1L20.9,95.6z"></path>
</clipPath>
```

Has anyone come across this before and knows whats happening here?

Comment: Hi @RobertLongson I have gotten the same issue. Do you think it's the scale values? But then again, why is duplicating it fixing it?

Comment: Thanks Robert, that makes a lot more sense about the duplication

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has an optimised code path for clips that have a single child. That codepath had a problem with processing transforms (it had the matrix math the wrong way round and matrix multiplication is not commutative).

This issue was tracked by [bug 712301](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1712301) and is fixed in Firefox 113